# How can I catch Mandrill Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, mandrill

I'm using the Mandrill API and trying to get some stats by a tag name

```
$mandrill = new \Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY);
return $mandrill->tags->info('campaign-117');
```

If the tag exists, it works fine. But if it doesn't exist yet (because I just sent the mails with the tag) the call throws an exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mandrill_Invalid_Tag_Name' with message 'no such tag "campaign-117"'
```

How can I catch this exception?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
try {
    $mandrill = new \Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY);
    return $mandrill->tags->info('campaign-117');
} catch(Mandrill_Invalid_Tag_Name $e) {
    ....
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
    ....
} catch(Exception $e) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I tried the exact same code against the last release from https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html and I can catch the Exception without any problem. Have you the last release ?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with namespaces, try `\Mandrill_Invalid_Tag_Name `?

Comment: @dbrumann, you are right. It was a namespace issue. Tanks a lot.